# Windows is shutting down screen takes a long 20 minutes

Tags: windows-xp, shutdown

I have an old Windows XP Pro SP1 machine that is having a problem shutting down.  In know that XP takes longer to shut down than to startup, but 20 minutes is a little excessive.  It always does shut down (eventually), but it stays on that "Windows is shutting down..." screen for about 20 minutes.

What may be causing it to take so long?  I removed the mapped network drives that are no longer in use, but I don't think that would make a difference.

Here is my HijackThis log for reference:

```
> Logfile of Trend Micro HijackThis
> v2.0.2 Scan saved at 11:06:31 AM, on
> 12/2/2009 Platform: Windows XP SP1
> (WinNT 5.01.2600) MSIE: Internet
> Explorer v6.00 SP1 (6.00.2800.1106)
> Boot mode: Normal
> 
> Running processes:
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\smss.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\winlogon.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\services.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\lsass.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\spoolsv.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\Ati2evxx.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\CDAC11BA.EXE
> C:\Program Files\Cisco Systems\VPN
> Client\cvpnd.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\LxrJD31s.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\pctspk.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\atiptaxx.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\ATK0100\Hcontrol.exe
> C:\Program Files\Common
> Files\Real\Update_OB\realsched.exe
> C:\Program
> Files\Java\j2re1.4.2_04\bin\jusched.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\ATK0100\ATKOSD.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\wuauclt.exe
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\wuauclt.exe
> C:\Program Files\Trend
> Micro\HijackThis\HijackThis.exe
> 
> R0 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet
> Explorer\Main,Local Page =  O2 - BHO:
> AcroIEHlprObj Class -
> {06849E9F-C8D7-4D59-B87D-784B7D6BE0B3}
> - C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 6.0\Reader\ActiveX\AcroIEHelper.dll O2 - BHO: (no name) - {53707962-6F74-2D53-2644-206D7942484F}
> - C:\PROGRA~1\SPYBOT~1\SDHelper.dll O3 - Toolbar: &Radio - {8E718888-423F-11D2-876E-00A0C9082467}
> - C:\WINDOWS\System32\msdxm.ocx O3 - Toolbar: (no name) -
> {BA52B914-B692-46c4-B683-905236F6F655}
> - (no file) O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [PCTVOICE] pctspk.exe O4 -
> HKLM\..\Run: [ATIModeChange]
> Ati2mdxx.exe O4 - HKLM\..\Run:
> [AtiPTA] atiptaxx.exe O4 -
> HKLM\..\Run: [Hcontrol]
> C:\WINDOWS\ATK0100\Hcontrol.exe O4 -
> HKLM\..\Run: [TkBellExe] "C:\Program
> Files\Common
> Files\Real\Update_OB\realsched.exe" 
> -osboot O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [SunJavaUpdateSched] C:\Program
> Files\Java\j2re1.4.2_04\bin\jusched.exe
> O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-19\..\Run:
> [CTFMON.EXE]
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\CTFMON.EXE (User
> 'LOCAL SERVICE') O4 -
> HKUS\S-1-5-20\..\Run: [CTFMON.EXE]
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\CTFMON.EXE (User
> 'NETWORK SERVICE') O4 -
> HKUS\S-1-5-18\..\Run: [CTFMON.EXE]
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\CTFMON.EXE (User
> 'SYSTEM') O4 - HKUS\.DEFAULT\..\Run:
> [CTFMON.EXE]
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\CTFMON.EXE (User
> 'Default user') O9 - Extra button: (no
> name) -
> {08B0E5C0-4FCB-11CF-AAA5-00401C608501}
> - C:\WINDOWS\System32\msjava.dll O9 - Extra 'Tools' menuitem: Sun Java
> Console -
> {08B0E5C0-4FCB-11CF-AAA5-00401C608501}
> - C:\WINDOWS\System32\msjava.dll O16 - DPF:
> {4ED9DDF0-7479-4BBE-9335-5A1EDB1D8A21}
> - http://bin.mcafee.com/molbin/shared/mcinsctl/en-gb/4,0,0,74/mcinsctl.cab
> O16 - DPF:
> {F58E1CEF-A068-4C15-BA5E-587CAF3EE8C6}
> (MSN Chat Control 4.5) -
> http://fdl.msn.com/public/chat/msnchat45.cab
> O17 -
> HKLM\System\CCS\Services\Tcpip\..\{1D93AED5-2A9C-4968-A6A2-C059EFB89F66}:
> NameServer = 158.152.1.58,158.152.1.43
> O17 -
> HKLM\System\CS1\Services\Tcpip\..\{1D93AED5-2A9C-4968-A6A
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I'm really more interested in solving the problem, rather than just masking the symptoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be anything from system performance to driver issues. Just have a look at the Windows XP Shutdown trouble shooter --> http://aumha.org/win5/a/shtdwnxp.htm

Also Make sure that your XP is Patched with this update [Patch](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=307274)

Comment: Basically, I just kep turning off services and disabling startup items until the problem went away.  It seems that there was a Cisco VPN service installed that was causing the hangup.  I couldn't figure out how to disable it, so I just uninstalled it, and the problem went away.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Try running [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com).

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the Windows XP to Service Pack 3. The service pack has performance and security improvements that may help you computer run more smoother. Run a virus scan and MRT tool as an added precaution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the event log, always a good place to start looking for the culprit(s).

As a temporary workaround, use this:

**[Superfast Shutdown](http://www.xp-smoker.com/freeware.html)** ... does exactly what it says on the tin.

[image]

*SuperFast Shutdown is freeware.*

Comment: It is not available anymore, right?